# MFC: How to open windows dialog "Open With" (Choose the program you want to use to open this file)?

Tags: winapi, mfc

When I right click on some file in windows in opened menu, there is an `Open With...` line, by clicking I can select some program, which will open selected file. So now I need to launch this dialog for some file (or just run for `"tmp.xml"` name) using `MFC`. I need something like `CFileDialog` which makes it possible to browse files.

I have found `SHOpenWithDialog`, but Minimum supported client for it is Windows Vista [desktop apps only], it would be better to support windows XP too.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found this kind of solution.

```
void OpenWith(CString strFileNameToOpen)
{
    TCHAR lpPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemDirectory(lpPathBuffer, MAX_PATH);
    CString strSystemDir = lpPathBuffer;
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    strSystemDir.Format(_T("rundll32.exe %s\\shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL %s"), lpPathBuffer, strFileNameToOpen);
    CreateProcess(NULL, strSystemDir.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```